How to show the snackbar above dialog box in flutter without using any gestures
I want to show the snackbar above the dialog box but it is showing behind the dialog box.
I have tried so many times and searched for its answer but it is not working. No need for extra gestures and without using the dependency flushbar. or If wrap with scaffold I have to use gestures for when I click outside the dialog box it disappears. I am not locating the appropriate place to use a scaffold

why not "wrapping with scaffold"? snackbar is part of scaffold anyway...

If I use then how i achieve snackbar above dialogbox? @pskink

instead of using "normal" dialogs (with showDialog function) use a padded Scaffold so that it does not occupy the entire screen - it will look like a dialog and its snackbar will be above it

I didn't get your point. Can you please elaborate or show me the code @pskink

use navigator to push a new rote where the root is not a Scaffold but a Padding with Scaffold child

can you give me some hint by it's code? @pskink
